# How to specify date standard when using .apply(pd.Timestamp). Python confusing date and month in 11/12/2018

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have two dataframes which both have a 'Date Time' column, the first dataframe has the data as `11/12/2018 15:34:04`, the second dataframe has the data as `2018-12-11 15:35:45`.

When I run df['Date Time'].apply(pd.Timestamp) I get the following:

The first dataframe becomes `2018-12-11 15:35:45`, which is correct. 
But the second dataframe becomes `2018-11-12 15:34:04` which is incorrect (the month and the date are in the wrong order).

I've had a look at the documentation and can't see a way to specify the order of the month/date. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: When you say you have a "Date Time" column - do you mean the `dtype` of those columns is `datetime`?

Comment: No, the column is just named "Date Time" I am converting it to a dtype = datetime column, but in the conversion processes it confuses the month and the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a better way is using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). For your second dataframe the code is going to be:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Date Time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Proof:

Prepare you case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date Time":["2018-12-11 15:35:45"]})   
df

Date Time
0   2018-12-11 15:35:45
```

Convert:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Date Time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
0   2018-12-11 15:35:45
Name: Date Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

PS

Should you be insisting on using `apply` the code will be:

```
df["Date Time"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
0   2018-12-11 15:35:45
Name: Date Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

but I never seen this in practice.

Comment: And the accepted string formats are here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior